# Regex Help -- Ignore in between quotes

Tags: java, regex

I know there's a million and one question & answers on Regex but I can't seem to find a straight-forward one that helps me solve this problem while also understanding it.

I want to take a String and ignore anything in the String that is between two quotes. For example,

```
String myString = "(\"You entered a value of \" + moneyAmount + \" 
dollars.\");";
```

How do I get it so anything between quotes ("You entered a value" and "dollars.") is forgotten? I would want my new String to be:

( + moneyAmount + );

Thank you and please help me understand regez!!

Comment: Don't delete downvoted questions.  You might still get useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\".*?\"` (but you have to escape the literal backslash and the quote, so it looks it a little funky). Like,

```
System.out.println(myString.replaceAll("\\\".*?\\\"", ""));
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
( + moneyAmount + );
```

Comment: this is a good solution